# Looping through combination of each paired element in python list

Tags: python, arrays, list, combinations

I have a list `l = ['a', 'b', 'c']` and I want to loop through the combination (order doesn't matter) of each paired elements of `l`. Doing

```py
import itertools
l= ['a', 'b', 'c']
for pair in itertools.product(l, l):
    print(pair)
```

yields:

```py
('a', 'a')
('a', 'b')
('a', 'c')
('b', 'a')
('b', 'b')
('b', 'c')
('c', 'a')
('c', 'b')
('c', 'c')
```

but I want something like:

```py
('a', 'a')
('a', 'b')
('a', 'c')
('b', 'b')
('b', 'c')
('c', 'c')
```

where the combinations like `('a', 'b')` and `('b', 'a')` doesn't repeat.
what is the best way to do this?

Comment: I.e. you only want the combinations where the first element of the pair is greater than or equal to the second? Or you only want unique combinations, where you consider `('a', 'b')` to  be equal to `('b', 'a')`?

Comment: yes I want the unique combinations where `('a', 'b')` is equal to `('b', 'a')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import itertools
l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for pair in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(l, 2):
    print(pair)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
arr=['a', 'b', 'c']
for i in range(len(arr)):
  for x in arr[i:]:
    print((arr[i],x))
```